# Localization of two rings which is an integral extension, then integral extension still holds?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Question seems simple, but I just can't find the solution.

Let $A/B$ be an integral ring extension and let $P$ be a prime ideal of $B$. By lying-over theorem, there is $Q$, a prime ideal of $A$, lying over $P$. Then the ring of fractions of $A$ localized on $Q$ is still integral on that of $B$ localized on $P$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: consider an example.

Here is one:  $A = \mathbb Z[i] \supset \mathbb Z = B$, $P = 5\mathbb Z$, $Q = (2+i)\mathbb Z[i].$

The element $1/(2-i)$ lies in $A_Q$.  Is it integral over $B_P$?

Comment: thanks for your exemple. I give a proof in the case for the field of fractions, when this proposition is true. [link](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/152303/localisation-of-two-rings-which-is-an-integral-extension-then-integral-extensio)